# How to create zoom on scroll effect through section or div into next one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, transform

I'm looking for zoom-in effect on scroll like this one: [click here to check](https://www.reformcollective.com/)
You can see it in the section with "REFORM CO" title.

Could anyone explain me where should I start to get more knowledge about that stuff? 
Is it create with translate3D or translateZ?
Should I use overlay title as PNG with transparent title, or somehow create div with transparent text over the next div?
And how to start zooming only when you are in "REFORM CO" section, and not from the beginning?

**If you can't tell me exactly what to do with it, please just give me any advice. Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

It is actually `scale` property that's working here and looks like a zoomed element.

This is how it works [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z5q3ord6/)

Just add an `onscroll()` instead of `onclick()` for scaling the element.

And to detect the percentage wise scroll of your page from top [PageScrolling](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/detect-user-scroll-amount.shtml)

And in this way by detecting when scrolled and element appears you can trigger the js for transforming the element and it will appear like zoomed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how to zoom through that into next section? I want to create "contact" title and scroll / zoom through it into contact form.

Comment: For this by detecting the page scroll from the given website set the `location.replace()` on the scroll percentage that you want and in that it will redirect you on the next page.